# How to apply the results of linear regression on a training set of data to a testing set of data?

Tags: r, linear-regression, training-data

I have two non-empty dataframes: `training` and `testing`. Each of these dataframes has two columns: `Y` and `X`, in this order. I have applied linear regression analysis to `training` as follows:

```
m <- lm(Y ~ X, data = training)
```

I would like to apply the coefficients resulting from this fitting to the data in `testing` to obtain the same types of information available in the object `m` for purposes of further analysis and data visualization. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about something like `predict(lm(Y ~ X, data=training), newdata=testing)`?

Comment: @r2evans: Yes, thanks. If I understand correctly, `testing`'s `Y` column is simply ignored by the `predict` function, right?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: @r2evans: But how does `predict` know to ignore `Y` rather than `X`?

Comment: When you start the regression with `lm(Y ~ X, ...)`, you are labeling `Y` as the response variable. The model retains this information, so then `predict()` knows this is the variable you are trying to predict based on the other variables (explanatory factors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `predict.lm` function:

```
Y_pred = predict(m, newdata = testing)
```